# Can't convert char to int value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, converters

See my code is below,

```
<div class="product_id" id="3"></div>

<?php
    $id = "<script>id = $('.product_id').attr('id');document.write(parseInt(id));</script>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo $id;
    echo "<br>";
    echo intval($id);
?>
```

If I execute this code output is,

```
3

0
```

I don't know why it's not converting. I need to display as,

```
3

3
```

Thanks

Comment: because it normal for intval($id) to return 0..

Comment: You seem a little confused about the scope of client side and server side variables.

Comment: never use `intval()`. Casting to integer `(int)` ie `echo (int)$id` is always faster,better, more legible (imo).

Comment: @gwillie I will agree with you

Comment: thanks @gwillie...But what about my ans?

Comment: what does echoing `$id` without `intval()` produce. Really, `intval()` should output `...the integer value of a variable...strings will most likely return 0 although this depends on the leftmost characters of the string`, directly from [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) manual. It should just work, but if it doesn't paste more code, and we'll go from there

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't know what JavaScript is displaying since it is running in the browser. Look at your sourcecode and you will see what I mean. The first "3" isn't actually "3". It's JavaScript code. The Javascript code is a string which intval "casts" to a "0".

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. This code will not work. When you need the "id" in PHP you have to get it with PHP, not JavaScript.

Comment: Any way to get with PHP?

Comment: With a regular expression for example:
preg_match('/<div[^>]*class="product_id"[^>]*id="([0-9]*)"/si', $html, $result)
But without knowing what this id is for it's difficult to give you a recommendation.

Comment: Is the HTML static or somehow generated?

Answer (score 0):

Try like.You need to `TypeCast` it like

```
echo (int)$id;
```

Answer (score 0):

`intval($id)` tries to turn `"<script>...</script>"` into an integer and of course fails. Take a look at the doc ([`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)), the "Return Values" section tells :

> The integer value of var on success, or **0 on failure**.

Also keep in mind that `echo` prints server side while `document.write` prints browser side. Now, let's have a look at your PHP code :

```
<div class="product_id" id="3"></div>
<?php
    $id = "<script>id = $('.product_id').attr('id');document.write(parseInt(id));</script>";
    echo "<br>";      // prints "<br>"
    echo $id;         // prints "<script>id = $('.product_id').attr('id');document.write(parseInt(id));</script>"
    echo "<br>";      // prints "<br>"
    echo intval($id); // prints "0" (since intval failed)
?>
```

Here is the resulting HTML loaded as is into the browser :

```
<div class="product_id" id="3"></div>
<br>
<script>id = $('.product_id').attr('id');document.write(parseInt(id));</script>
<br>
0
```

Comment: OMG! Ok Man. Now What to do?

Comment: @KarSho I guess you want to post `id` from the browser (js) to the server (php). In this case, you'll have to use either an HTML form or an Ajax request.

Comment: HTML form? How? Can you tell, please?

Comment: @KarSho It's a bit too complex to explain here. You should read this tutorial instead : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp.

Comment: @KarSho Now, if you understand why you "Can't convert char to int value", you may accept any answer you want, and optionally vote up for cool dudes who tried to help you.